# How to join Applescript paths?

Tags: applescript

Is there a more direct way to join paths together than to convert to and from a POSIX path in Applescript? For example:

```
POSIX file (POSIX path of (path to desktop folder) & "hello.txt")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate HFS paths (colon separated) this way

```
(path to desktop as text) & "hello.txt"
```

`path to desktop` returns an alias specifier.
The parameter `as text` coerces the alias specifier to HFS path